# mysql query gets slower as it travels farther?

Tags: .net, mysql, performance

Here is my query. According to the log it takes about a second to query the results. Many loops later (offset 17100) it takes 15+seconds. Why? In create table defined id as

```
`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

Here is my code/query

```
Console.WriteLine("1 {0} {1}", DateTime.Now, offset);
var res = conn.Query<PageInfo2>("select * from tbl order by id limit @o, 300", new { o = offset });
Console.WriteLine("2 {0} {1}", DateTime.Now, offset);
offset += res.Count();
foreach (var v in res)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you do not have a WHERE condition, the engine most likely does a full table scan, which explains longer delays with higher offsets.

When you do not have a where condition, basically you are reading the table like a highly fragmented text file.

Comment: Shouldnt it be optimized via limit and using the id as an index?

Comment: It doesn't in most cases. You can force it by using a where condition, if your ID values are contiguous. Ex.
select * from Table1 where ID > 1000 order by ID desc Limit 100

Comment: Thats really fck'd up that it would look at so many rows when i limit it

Answer (score 2):

You can also try using the EXPLAIN command to see how many rows are scanned with each SELECT. As in the previous answer, the WHERE can help you select only the id above your initial limit parameter.

Comment: It does tell me. The row count is >300 (its 608 at one example) but its not as many as with the limit. Thats kind of messed it would look at so many rows